# How to check if staff member has end date with a Null value

Tags: sql-server-2016, count, null

I have a database that records employees tasks throughout the organisation and when they finish etc., I need to identify if each employee, has at least one row with a null value in either finish.

Basically - show me any employee_no that does not have at least one row with a null value in column Finish.

There can be more than one null value but as long as there's one.

Sample database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT employee_no
FROM source_table
GROUP BY employee_no
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(finish)
```

---

> Is there a way to include the whole table in that sequence? – Chris
>
> `select serverproperty('ProductVersion') as [version], serverproperty('Edition') as [edition]` and got Version 13.0.5102.14 of edition Devleoper Edition (64-bit) – Chris
>
> This is (Microsoft) SQL server 2016 SP2. – Akina

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Employee_No,
                     Task,
                     Start,
                     Finish, 
                     MAX(CASE WHEN Finish IS NULL 
                              THEN 1 
                              ELSE 0 
                              END) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_no) have_nulls
              FROM source_table
            )
SELECT Employee_No,
       Task,
       Start,
       Finish
FROM cte
WHERE have_nulls = 0
/* ORDER BY 1,2,3 */
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Akina.

Comment: Is there a way to include the whole table in that sequence? So I could filter out certain Tasks?

Comment: @Chris The ways exists always. But simple way - version-dependent. What is your MySQL version?

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Studio. Apologise for the incorrect SQL tag.

Comment: @Chris Azure Data Studio is client software, not DBMS. This info is unnesessary and useless.

Comment: My apologise Akina I'm not an expert on the version side of SQL. I'll check with a colleague it could be Microsoft Transact SQL but I'll confirm.

Comment: @Chris Try to execute `SELECT VERSION();`...

Comment: That code wouldn't run.. I tried this code:

Comment: select serverproperty('ProductVersion') as [version],
    serverproperty('Edition') as [edition]

and got Version 13.0.5102.14 of edition Devleoper Edition (64-bit)

Comment: This is (Microsoft) SQL server 2016 SP2. Re-tag your question...

Comment: @Chris Query added - check.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Akinas solution (which probably is better), we can use the fact that null is treated lower than any real value:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT st.*
         , FIRST_VALUE(finish) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_no
                                     ORDER BY finish) as fst
    FROM t
) as u
WHERE fst IS NOT NULL
```